# why can't I use ipython

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I use os x system and I installed Ipython successfully through pip in terminal. And I pass 11 out of the 14 iptest, but it seems make no difference in my interpreter
in both version 2.7 and 3.4. I tried some basic commend of Ipython but none of them work. I could launch the Ipython notebook though.
     Thanks for any help.

Comment: I assume that you fixed the problem by now. Otherwise , you might want to place some messages that are generated when you start IPython or the *iptest* outputs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest workaround, if you do not need interactive graphics, is to change to a non-interactive backend. Go the Canopy / Preferences menu, select "Python", and under "Pylab backend", select "Inline (SVG)".

Here's a link to help you in depth for OSX Python :

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469330-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks-Python-Canopy